# Flutter BlocConsumer builder only called once, but listener and BlocObserver see states changes as expected?

Tags: flutter, event-handling, bloc

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. I'm using Bloc 8.0 and noticed that if an event handler is emitting multiple state changes very quickly, BlocListener and BlocObserver "catch" all the state changes, but BlocBuilder only catches the last one.

To be clear - I can confirm my bloc changes states correctly, this is not a problem of emitting the same state and bloc is not updating (like in many other questions about bloc builder/listener not firing).

If I emit the changes with some delays using Future.delayed, it works.

So to summarize:

In this case, I see all emits identified by the listener of a BlocConsumer, ***but not by the builder***:

```
emit(state.copyWith(someStringValue: "aaa"));
emit(state.copyWith(inputWord: "bbb"));
emit(state.copyWith(inputWord: "ccc"));
```

But it I delay the emits it is showing in ***both the listener and builder***:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
 emit(state.copyWith(someStringValue: "aaa"));
});

await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
 emit(state.copyWith(inputWord: "bbb"));
});

await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
 emit(state.copyWith(inputWord: "ccc"));
});
```

Is this the expected behavior? I suspect it's a gap in my understanding of how blocbuilder works.

Comment: This is actually expected behavior. Flutter framework allows us to only rebuild widgets at 60fps. Any faster than that won't quickly re-render hence the last state persists. 

Solutions exist like the one you did. It is a closed issue and you can refer to this link: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2282